# Hosting and accessing my server behind a router?

Tags: networking, routes, udp, enet

I'm testing a network library called enet. When I make connections on port 1720 using 192.168. ips, my laptop (client) connects to my PC (host) no problem. When I connect my PC with PPPOE and use the new ip (76.86...) then I never get anything.

I've tried forwarding port 1720 to the PC,forwarding it to the laptop, using DMZ, nothing at all works. What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are the PC and laptop both connected to the same cable/adsl router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 76.86.. address will be assigned to your router, not the PC so what is probably happening is that the router is forwarding traffic that comes in to port 1720 on that address to your PC as you have configured it to do, but traffic from your laptop to that 76.86.. address will just stop at the router because it is coming in from a LAN port so will not get forwarded in the same way that traffic from outside does.

Answer (score 0):

Port 1720 definitely needs to be forwarded to your  PC (the host).  Is your host a Windows machine? If so, check to see if Windows firewall is enabled.  I am not familiar with enet, but is there a chance that it uses multiple ports?

Comment: It is Windows. What do you mean by multiple ports?

Comment: First thing's first, check to see if windows firewall is enabled on the host.  If so, disable it and test.  I wouldn't recommend leaving it off, you can create an allow rule for that port.

Comment: Nope, it is not the Windows Firewall.